# (long) list of ggplots in R. Specify relative size when plotting with grid.arrange or ggarange

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, igraph

I have a series of small disconnected networks (more than 115, size between 2 and 20) that need to be plotted together. I created a list of ggplot objects, and I would like to plot the networks on a grid.

This can be done with

```
grid.arrange(grobs=plots)
```

however, this means that all the networks are of the same size. I would like bigger networks (say networks whose size is bigger than 10) to occupy "twice" as much space as the others on the plot. I am not picky on the definition of bigger and on how much bigger it is, as I am looking for something tunable to different needs.

I know that with grid.arrange one can specify relative widths and heights, but I have so many plots that doing it manually it is quite annoying.

Any chance I can do that?

Here a simple version of the code to play with:

```
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)


list_of_networks <- list()
for (i in 1:5){
  list_of_networks[[i]] <- erdos.renyi.game(n=18,p=0.6)
}  
for (i in 6:80){
  list_of_networks[[i]] <- erdos.renyi.game(n=3,p=0.6)
}
plots<-list()
for(i in 1:length(list_of_networks)) {
  fr.all <- layout_with_fr(list_of_networks[[i]])
  fr.all.df <- as.data.frame(fr.all)
  fr.all.df$name = V(list_of_networks[[i]])$name
 

  ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=fr.all.df,aes(x=V1,y=V2),size=3,colour="red2") +
    geom_point(data=fr.all.df,aes(x=V1,y=V2),size=2,colour="black") +scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,1))+  # expand the x limits 
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,1))+ # expand the y limits
    theme_void() -> plots[[i]]
}

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plots,ncol=9)
```

and this is the plot I get. Notice how cramped the first networks are compared to the rest.

[image]